# Flask-Mail not sending email

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I want to receive an email when users fill out a contact form and submit it but instead of sending the email it just displays the email as part of the URL. I have tried several methods but it's not working at all and even in the code, it does not show any errors.
This is my code for the function

```
from app import app, mail
from flask import render_template, request
from flask_mail import Message


def send_mail(contactform):
    msg = Message('Porfolio Contact Applicant',
                  recipients=['rynato@kellychibale-researchgroup-uct.com'],
                  sender='Portfolio-Maxwell@portfoliomaxwell.co.ke')
    msg.body = ''' 
    Hello there, 
    You have just received contact details form from your portfolio

    Name: {}
    Email: {}
    Message: {}
   
'''.format(contactform['name'], contactform['email'], contactform['message'] )

    mail.send(msg)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contactform = request.form
        
        contactform = {}

        contactform['name'] = request.form['name']
        contactform['email ']= request.form['email'].repalces(' ','').lower()
        contactform['message ']= request.form['message']

        send_mail(contactform)

        return render_template('index.html', **locals())

    else:
        return render_template('index.html', **locals())       


@app.route('/privacy')
def privacy():
    return render_template('privacy.html')
```

so does anyone have a clue as what do or go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer(s) might depend on the type of email you want to sent, and how you have to connect to your preferred service provider.

Here's one example.

In Forms.py

```
class SendEmailForm(FlaskForm):
    confirmed = BooleanField('confirmed')
    to = StringField("to",  validators=[DataRequired("Please enter the email address you want to send to")])
    subject = StringField("subject", [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=1, max=80)])
    message_text = TextAreaField('message_text', [validators.DataRequired()] , render_kw={"rows": 10, "cols": 60} )
    submit = SubmitField("submit")
```

In Models.py

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

def SendEmailMessage(to, subject, messagetext, messagehtml, cc):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    msg = EmailMessage()
    sender = app.config['MAIL_ADMIN_NAME']
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.set_content(messagetext)

    # Try to log in to server and send email
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],app.config['MAIL_PORT'])
        server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
        server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
        server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
        server.login(app.config['MAIL_ADMIN_NAME'], app.config['MAIL_ADMIN_PSSWRD'])
        server.send_message(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        # Print any error messages to stdout
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

In Views:

```
@app.route('/send_email', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send_email():
    form = SendEmailForm()
    sender = app.config['MAIL_ADMIN_NAME']

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('email requested to {}, confirmed={}'.format(
            form.to.data, form.confirmed.data))

        to = form.to.data
        subject = form.subject.data
        message_text = form.message_text.data
        confirmed = form.confirmed.data

        if confirmed == True:
            cc = ""
            SendEmailMessage(to, subject, message_text, message_text, cc)
            flash('Please check your email inbox.')
    else:
        print("Not validated")

    return render_template("send_email.html",
                           title='Send an email',
                           sender=sender,
                           form=form,
                           footer_text=footer_text)
```

In send_email.html

```
<p>
Hello "{{ sender }}".
</p>

<div>
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        Please tick the checkbox if you would to send your email. 
    </p>
     <p>Confirmed : 
        <input type="checkbox" name="confirmed"/>
     </p>

     <p>
      Send to: <br>
     {{ form.to }}<br>
      {% for error in form.to.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}
     </p>

     <p>Subject of email: <br>
        <input type="textbox" name="subject"/><br>
      {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}
     </p>

     <p>Email message<br>
        <textarea cols="70" id="message_text" name="message_text" required rows="10" size="2400"></textarea><br>
      {% for error in form.message_text.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}
     </p>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue">
      </p>
</form> 
</div>
```